# Not returning anything from postgresql function in Java EE callablestatement

Tags: postgresql, rest, jakarta-ee, jboss, plpgsql

I'm calling a Postgresql Function in my Java EE code, but it doesn't return anything there.(it has results in sql query)

```
public List<Integer> convertIdsToLats12(Integer src, Integer dest) {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource source = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/RoutingDS");
        Connection connection = source.getConnection();

        CallableStatement statement = connection
                .prepareCall("{ ? = call pgr_astar( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) }");
        statement
                .setString(
                        2,
                        "SELECT gid AS id, source::integer, target::integer, length::double precision AS cost, x1, y1, x2, y2 FROM waysF");
        statement.setObject(3, src);
        statement.setObject(4, dest);
        statement.setBoolean(5, false);
        statement.setBoolean(6, false);
        statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);

        System.out.println("*************AVANT");
        statement.execute();
        System.out.println("*************APRES");

        resultSet = (ResultSet) statement.getObject(1);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            ids.add((Integer) resultSet.getObject(2));
        }
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Here is my method, is there any problem with it?

Comment: There's no such thing as `JEE` - I assume you mean JavaEE? What exactly are you using - application server/framework and version, PostgreSQL version, PgJDBC version. Also, did you look at the PostgreSQL server error log?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is critically wrong - you have an empty `catch` block. Never do that. Ever. It's known as "silently swallowing" an exception and is a great way to mask errors, so you can't see what's really happening.

Remove it and add `throws SQLException` to the method declaration, or put some code to log any caught exception, like:

```
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.severe("Whoops, query failed" + e);
}
```

Most likely that will tell you what's going wrong. (Obviously you should write a better error message than this, preferably including the full exception stack trace, query text, parameters, etc. This is just a basic example.)

You should never `catch (Exception e)` anyway. Catch specific exception types, as required. It's bad programming practice and will lead to you catching exceptions you didn't mean to.

Comment: well, thanks for all
Now i have "A CallableStatement was executed with an invalid number of parameters" exception

Comment: @KhaledSmiri Odd. The param count matches the input params as far as I can tell. What PgJDBC version are you using? (You should always give your PgJDBC version and PostgreSQL version in all questions). Also, what's the output of `\df pgr_astar` in `psql`

Comment: Thanks for all, i solved the problem with:                        Query query=entitymanager.createnativeqyery("My Query");
return query.getresultlist();

Comment: thank you for your advices, i wasn't been able to solve my problems without

Comment: Well, worked around it. It doesn't really answer what was wrong in the first place, but w/o the version info etc I can't help more anywya.